# PHP String Edit - Simple

Tags: php

I am creating a website that pulls data from a CSV file and then displays the album artwork that matches the album and artist however I've hit a snag... the file presents artists as either a band (example: U2) or the artist (Dylan, Bob) the later does not work with the api.

I've tried to no success to edit the string so if it sees "," it will then rearrange the artist from `last, first` to `first last`

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Cheers!

Comment: *rubs crystal ball* line 12, character 5 needs to be upper case! In seriousness though, we'll need to see your code before we can give any real help.

Comment: Do you mean you can't rearrange the string, or it still doesn't work after you have rearranged it?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Is the CSV file correct or do the additional `,` result in a problem? You mentioned an API...do you mean PHP or are you using some library?

Comment: please improve your question, not clear.

Comment: I hope your CSV is quoting special characters or you'll never get it to work

Comment: Sorry for not giving more information and actual code. The solution however has been resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`explode()` on `,` (comma-space) into variables `$last, $first`. If `$first` is nonempty, rearrange them. Otherwise, just output the original `$fullname`.

```
$fullname = "Dylan, Bob";

$parts = explode(", ", $fullname);
$first = isset($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : NULL;
$last = $parts[0];
if (!empty($first)) {
  $output = "$first $last";
}
else $output = $fullname;
```

Comment: `$first` will always be populated because (annoyingly) [`list()` populates from right to left](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php#refsect1-function.list-notes). So you would need to do `if ($last)`. I think.

Comment: @DaveRandom  Yes, looks to be so. I made some changes accordingly.

Comment: This seems to be the best one so far! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A regex might work for you:

```
if( preg_match("#(\w+),\s?(\w+)#", $artist) )
    $artist = preg_replace("#(\w+),\s?(\w+)#", "\2 \1", $artist)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "Dylan, Bob";
$fixed = preg_replace('/^(.*), (.*)$/', '$2 $1' , $string);
```